# Why is script tag defined in contentPlaceHolder not being added?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to dynamically add some javascript to my view in a contentPlaceHolder. For some reason the  is never added. The foreach logic directly beneath is run however.

What's with that?

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="DynamicIncludes" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   alert("why am I not firing?");
</script>   

<%foreach (var script in Model.DynamicIncludes)
  {%>

      <%=Html.ScriptTag(Url.Content(script))%>

  <%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: So you don't get anything at all coming through - e.g. not even the `<script>` tags? Is the page using the main masterpage file or a child masterpage file?

Comment: The main master page. If I add an alert() to the script it is never fired.

Comment: When you view the source of the html in your browser, can you see the tags and what not? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Weird. Can you show the Page directive for the view, a `<asp:Content>` tag in that view that is working and the masterpage code where you define the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` that is working and the one that isn't working - *DynamicIncludes*.

Comment: add `runat="server"` to script tag, any difference?

Comment: Thanks! I'm a dummy. @Charlino you had me double checking my master page to find that I had not yet added the ContentPlaceHolder. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its important to remember to actually define the contentPlaceHolder in the master page. Duh.